# Efficiently draw polygons (one color per polygon) in OpenGL 3+

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

In an application I have to draw lots of disjoint polygons of variable lengths. Colours vary between polygons but all vertices in a single polygon will have the same colour. How can I draw them efficiently?

I started by drawing all polygons with the same colour. This was easy to do with `glMultiDrawArrays` and a colour uniform; for example (using `GL_LINE_LOOP` to keep things simple):

```
glUniform4f(shaderColourLocation, red, blue, green, alpha);
glMultiDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, pFirstIndices, pPolygonSizes, polygonCount);
```

This worked well with the data I have, but the only ways I can see to add per-polygon colours are:

- break this down into multiple `glDrawArrays` calls, setting the colour each time (lots of extra API calls);
- buffer per-vertex colour data (duplicates a lot of colour data);
- buffer polygon indices and use a uniform array of colours (more complex, and still some redundant data).

Is there a better way to achieve per-polygon colours, while still using `glMultiDrawArrays` or something similar?

Comment: don't be afraid to duplicate the color data.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve (one color per polygon) is called *flat shading*.

You probably can do it width a shader by using [the `flat` qualifier](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Interpolation_qualifiers).

You also can take a look to [glShadeModel](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml) parameter, by using `GL_FLAT` mode and smartly define the first vertex of your triangles you may avoid to duplicate data in your buffers.

You can find documentation in [the OpenGl compatibility specs](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.compatibility.pdf) (p482 #507/953 §13.4).

Comment: The line loop still looks per line to see which attribute to pass on, so this doesn't absolve you from passing the correct color into the vertex shader.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, you are right, my response is about polygon rendering. Edited my answer to emphasis that.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***instanced attributes***.

---

Call

```
glVertexAttribDivisor(color_attrib_location, 1);
```

once when initializing your vertex arrays.

With this setting you will only need one copy of color value per point/line/polygon.

Also, you should use `flat` interpolation qualifier for this attribute in your shaders, but it's not necessary.

Comment: instancing will just redraw the *same mesh* with the *same uniforms* and only the attributes set in glVertexAttribDivisor will differ between instances.